# Where does bash store the time commands were executed?

Tags: bash, command-history, storage, timestamps

Enabling `history` to display time via  `export HISTTIMEFORMAT='%F %T '` shows the times of the commands but `.bash_history` doesn't contain any times.

Where does `bash` store the times the commands were executed?

Are they always stored automatically?

Comment: I just checked via `history | less` and all the commands from some hours back use the same time, so it is probably storing the times only for the current session

Comment: possible duplicate of [Finding command execution time in hindsight](http://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/44686/finding-command-execution-time-in-hindsight)

Comment: @slm not a dupe, this one is asking where the information is stored, not how to get it.

Comment: @terdon - retracted, but still feels like a dup to me. The only new thing here is the `history -a` bit.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From the [`BASH_BUILTINS`](http://www.unix.com/man-page/all/7/bash-builtins/) man page:

> **If** the  `HISTTIMEFORMAT`  variable  is set, the time stamp information associated with each history entry is written to the history file, marked with the history comment character.  When the  history  file  is  read, lines  beginning  with  the  history  comment  character followed immediately by a digit are interpreted as timestamps for the previous history line.

So the information is stored in the history file only if `HISTTIMEFORMAT` is set.

(Try `history -a` to append the currently in-memory history entries to your history file. You should now see comments with unix timestamps in there.)