# Why doesn't the bash commands history save datetimes by default in Linux/Debian?

Tags: linux, bash, logs, command-history, timestamps

The bash history does not display or even just save the datetimes of when commands where run. This severely limits the usefulness of the bash history and I can't see any good rationale for it. One can enable storing the datetimes by running:

`echo 'export HISTTIMEFORMAT="%d/%m/%y %T "' >> ~/.bash_profile && source ~/.bash_profile`
(or `sudo echo 'export HISTTIMEFORMAT="%d/%m/%y %T "' >> ~/.bashrc && source ~/.bashrc`)

But this is only applied after the above command has been run by the user. The `history` command could simply be changed so that by default the datetimes are not printed by default but at least they could be - e.g. by running something like `history -t`.

The advantages of having datetimes are obvious - e.g. one might experience a problem and wish to see which commands were run at about the time it first occurred, or print all commands run in a specific time period, or wants to check if the bash history is complete with no timespans missing, or wants to analyze the times of when commands were run, or wants to check when a specific command was run, ...

This question is about GNU/Linux in general as I think this could be changed at a root level instead of at the level of specific distros like Debian. I don't know if any distros store commands' datetimes by default but that wouldn't be the solution here.

**This is not a question about opinions but about the historic rationale for not saving datetimes by default in Linux/Debian.**

---

<sup>Another decision that's inexplicable to me is (the maintenance of) a very low `HISTSIZE` and `HISTFILESIZE` variables which - for no good reason - restricts the number of entries in the command history, severely limits its use, can't be explained by concerns about disk space and requires users to somehow learn about this limit and change it accordingly before it's exceeded to have a complete bash history. But that's probably a separate thing. I also don't see why currently in-memory history entries are [not](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/107702/233262) appended to the history immediately after executing them but are instead kept in suspense/vulnerable to loss (also a separate problem). Worst of all, there doesn't seem to be a well-visible option in a GUI (like KDE's system settings or the konsole's settings window) to change the HISTSIZE HISTFILESIZE and `HISTTIMEFORMAT` settings.</sup>

Answer (score 1):

> can't be explained by concerns about disk space

Initial release June 8, 1989; 31 years ago

Most common HDDs from that era: 20, 32, 40MB: https://www.quora.com/What-was-the-biggest-HDD-capacity-in-the-1980s

Disk space was very limited and very expensive back then.